# how to generate brief of a html article?

Tags: python

```
a= <div><xxxx.......<a>....</a></div>
```

I want to make a blog app by web2py,i want to generate a brief of the content,maybe first 50 words of the content. but if i use a[:50] the html tag will be error. is there some easy functions to do this?

Comment: Take a look at the BeautifulSoup module: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: I got the answer
https://gist.github.com/dcrosta/1339994